# Datetime Format in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to display the datetime automatically according to the current culture in the environment.

For example
If I use `DateTime.ToShortDateString()` to convert the `Datetime` of "May 4 2013",it will be `4/5/2013` in en-us and `5/4/2013` in `en-gb`.

But what I want to display is `04/05/2013` in en-us and `05/04/2013` in en-gb. The zero cannot be hidden.

And please be noted that the software may be run in various cultures, not just in USA and UK. I don't want to set the datetime format for each culture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that .NET has its own idea of what each culture's formatting should be, there's not much you can do short of deciding to "improve" on the existing formats.

What I'd do is create an `IValueConverter` in which I'd take the current (or desired) culture's short date format:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

And replace any occurences of a single `d` with a `dd`.

If you require months to have double digits and years to be four digit long, I'd replace single `M` with `MM` and make sure there's always four `y`'s.

This approach takes advantage of what .NET considers to be the right order for the date-month-year in each culture and uses what .NET considers to be the right separator too.

The converter might look like this:

```
class ShortDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object data, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string format = PrepareFormat(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);

    DateTime date = (DateTime)data;

    return date.ToString(format, culture);
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object data, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return DateTime.ParseExact((string)data, PrepareFormat(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern), culture);
  }

  private string PrepareFormat(string format)
  {
    if (!format.Contains("dd"))
      format = format.Replace("d", "dd");

    if (!format.Contains("MM"))
      format = format.Replace("M", "MM");

    if (!format.Contains("yyyy"))
      format = format.Replace("yy", "yyyy");

    return format;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why should you get this complicated using a IValueConverter when you can let the Framework decide how to display the `DateTime` object?

Comment: Because the OP doesn't want to let the framework decide. He wants to make sure that days have a leading zero, for example, which is not always the case in .NET date patterns for all cultures. With the `IValueConverter` he'd get order and separators right *and* leading zeroes where needed.

Comment: One point... there are 4 format specifiers for year: `y`, `yy`, `yyy`, `yyyy`.  The `format.Replace("yy", "yyyy")` will produce an illegible result if the `yyy` form is present.  Apart from that... good answer. +1

Comment: Indeed, the replacement part might be a little naive and could look more like Corey's.

Answer (score 0):

The culture-specific formats will define whether or not leading zeros are present.  To change that you'll need to parse the date format specified by the culture, look for non-leading-zero specifiers and synthesize a format that includes leading zeros.

For instance:

```
static string ShortDateFormat(string culture = null)
{
    CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);

    DateTimeFormatInfo fmtinfo = ci.DateTimeFormat;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fmtinfo.DateSeparator))
        return fmtinfo.ShortDatePattern;

    string fmt = fmtinfo.ShortDatePattern.Replace(fmtinfo.DateSeparator, "!");
    string[] parts = fmt.Split('!');

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (parts[i] == "d")
            parts[i] = "dd";
        else if (parts[i] == "M")
            parts[i] = "MM";
    }

    return string.Join(fmtinfo.DateSeparator, parts);
}
```

Maybe a bit overboard... I don't know if there are any cultures that use a date separator that is more than a single character :)

Pass the result of that as a parameter to `DateTime.ToString()` to get your output.

Comment: *I don't know if there are any cultures that use a date separator that is more than a single character* - There are! But not many. Some cultures use separators like `. ` (note the space after period) for example.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Good thing I didn't assume there weren't then :P